# I want to add a scheduler to my workflow

Tags: python, workflow, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, worker

This image depicts my current workflow.

[image]

Lots of work added to a queue, with workers polling the queue getting work and working.

```
  def doWork():
       doTask1()
       doTask2()
```

How would adding a scheduler/clock to this current flow improve things now and in the future?

Comment: Have you attempted anything yourself yet?

Comment: yes i have the current flow in code. not really asking for code but understanding on how a scheduler would improve the current flow, if at all.

Comment: Could you be more specific. The choice of a scheduler strongly depends how your tasks interact. The easiest thing is to run each task in a separate thread or program and let the operating system take care of the load balancing.

Comment: so a scheduler is to used to ease pain on workers...? my workers are currently asking the queue for as much work as possible constantly, maybe I dont need a scheduler at this time